# Looking for Qt SMPP Client

Tags: c++, qt, smpp

I can't find any SMPP libraries for Qt. Does it exists?
Or how to attach it to my project?

Can somebody advice for me any issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SMPP is a rather specific protocol.  Qt is more of a general purpose desktop and mobile development platform.

This looks like a LGPL licensed C++ project:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/smppcxx/